# Uncompress .Z files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compression

Is there anyway I can extract contents of a `.Z` file in MATLAB? I have tried MATLAB functions `unzip`, `gunzip` and `untar` and nothing has worked for me.

Comment: Are you on a Linux machine?

Comment: No. Windows. I can uncompress these files using winrar manually but I want to know how to do it in Matlab.

Comment: Have you tried using `system` in conjunction with WinRAR?

Comment: Yes but it only opens in a new window. I only want to uncompress files in the same folder without opening so that I can open the files with my code to process data. I have to uncompress hundreds of files at a time.

Comment: You can use WinRAR in command line mode.

Comment: I view some files on `/MatLab 5.3/ARCHIVES` folder, But I can't extract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with writing a Matlab function that calls the Linux/Windows command (in this case `uncompress name.z`)? On Linux, something like this :

```
function uncompress(filename)

   str = ['uncompress', '  ', filename]; % note the blank

   system(str);
```

On Windows, you can use 7zip:

```
function uncompress(filename)

   path_to_7z='C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'; % adapt to your path

   str = [path_to_7z, ' ', filename]; % note the blank

   system(str);
```

Now you can use your the Matlab's brand new uncompress function :

`>>uncompress('file_to_uncompress.z')`

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please clarify it a little bit more.

Comment: This is not valid MATLAB syntax. MATLAB's string operations are not Pythonic

Comment: Matlab has several ways to execute external commands (this is what you need to do), one of them is `system`  [link] (http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/05/17/calling-shell-commands-from-matlab/) . In this case you just build a string that is valid windows/linux command and then pass this string to `system`.

Comment: Yes, I know how MATLAB works. `str = path_to_7z + ' ' + filename;` doesn't work in MATLAB. Well, it does, but it's not string concatenation.

Comment: You are definitely right! I wasn't focused ...for a moment! ;)

Comment: @eddie `strcat` trims trailing whitespace from all inputs so your usage with `' '` as the second input won't work. You should just use `[]`: `['uncompress ', filename]` or `sprintf('uncompress %s', filename)`